# code examples for storing listview into sqlite database and within onclicklistener?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

does anyone have good code examples of inserting listview into sqlite database? i googled how to insert listview into database but most have examples on how to display listview from database instead. so yah please help me thanks!

Comment: is it like you have a listview and you want to click on it and all the details in it gets inserted into a database???

Comment: yeah! do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {

 //get clickedItem details using position and insert these details into the database table.
                }
            }
        });
```

listView is your list view. the integer parameter "position" gives you the ListView item position you clicked. using that you can get the details

details can be fetched something like this:

```
String[] items = {"", "", .....};
```

you populate the listView using this String array and then get the details of the clickd item using

```
String clickedItem = String[position];
```

now insert these details into your database table.